# failure discovery using LLDP

Tags: routing, linux-networking, network-topology

I have a array of switches connected to an Openflow controller.I want to understand the topology of the switches.I am thinking of using LLDP for this.Now in this architecture if a link goes down or a switch stop functioning is there some mechanism for failure discovery? What I guess I am basically asking is are there some mechanism for failure discovery in LLDP.?
I had a look at the wikipedia page and I couldn't find much on it.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

LLDP isn't designed for failure discovery - it's a standards compatible way of doing topology discovery. If you're looking to do failure discovery, you probably want something like [BFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_Forwarding_Detection) (if you're using routing between the ports), or the failure detection built into ethernet auto negotiation (if you're not).